# How do I change a variable inside a function ever iteration of a loop?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to have a boolean variable flip (True becomes False, False becomes True), and this variable is inside of a function. However, I have an issue where I either have to assign the variable inside the function (thus having the variable reset to what I assigned it to inside the function), or don't do that, which causes an UnboundLocalError. Any help on this would be great.

I was creating a function, click(), which flips a boolean every iteration of a loop

```
def click():
    alternate = True #not doing this will cause an error
    alternate = not alternate #flipping the variable
```

and then having a loop run using the function

```
while True:
    click()
    print(alternate) #constantly prints False
```

while what I wanted was to print True, False, True, etc.

Comment: You probably want to use "global alternate" inside your function.

Comment: @KenShirriff I tried this, it didn't change anything

Comment: I made an answer that explains `global` in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python does not have pass by reference. it has mutable and immutable variables.
so if your variable is mutable you need to return the value each time and reset it like this:

```
def click(alternate):
    alternate = not alternate #flipping the variable
    return alternate
```

and:

```
alternate = True
while True:
    alternate=click(alternate )
    print(alternate) #constantly prints False
```

Comment: And then I need to flip what I put inside click(). Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe the term you're looking for is "pass by assignment". Mutability has less to do with it (although one conceivable solution is to assign values inside a mutable container). Even if the instance is mutable, you still wouldn't be able to completely replace the object, which requires assignment (requiring the same solution as you are providing for a `bool` response type).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a global variable:

```
alternate = True

def click():
    global alternate
    alternate = not alternate #flipping the variable

while True:
    click()
    print(alternate)
```

There are two things to note. First, the variable is defined *outside* the function. Section, the `global` statement *inside* the function lets the function modify the variable. For more about global vs. local variables, see the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value).

Global variables are generally frowned upon, though, since they make the code harder to test and make it harder to follow what is going on. If you end up with multiple global variables, you might want to consider putting them in a class so they are encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reference your `alternate` variable in the `click()` function to the global `alternate` variable
this works for me:

```
alternate = True

def click():
    global alternate
    alternate = not alternate
    print(alternate) 

while True:
    click()
```

Answer (score -2):

Note - As pointed by @hamed-danesh this is not how python works and my answer is wrong. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77424705/18958931 .

You can use a global variable `alternate`
ex -

```
alternate = True #global varaible
    
def click():
    alternate = not alternate #flipping the variable

while True:
    click()
    print(alternate) #prints False, True, False, True
```

or maybe pass the value of `alternate` as an argument (if you have a restriction where `click()` cannot access the variable).

Comment: this is not correct. `alternate` is in a different scope within the function and module level. The assignment in `click` here would lead to an `UnboundLocalError` because `alternate` is created separately in the function scope, meaning it is unbound on the RHS. You need to declare the variable as `global alternate` at the start of the function.

Comment: This is not right, python see this as two variables. A global variable named alternate and a local variable named alternate inside click function

Comment: Got it. I used Java/JS/C logic and thought it'll be same for python but I was wrong. It's been long since I coded in python. It's indeed a weird language for programmers.